# Install a new node dependency inside a Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose

Considering the following development environment with Docker:

```
# /.env
CONTAINER_PROJECT_PATH=/projects/my_project

# /docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    restart: always
    build: ./docker/web
    working_dir: ${CONTAINER_PROJECT_PATH}
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:${CONTAINER_PROJECT_PATH}
      - ./node_modules:${CONTAINER_PROJECT_PATH}/node_modules

# /docker/web/Dockerfile
FROM keymetrics/pm2:latest-alpine
FROM node:8.11.4

ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global

RUN mkdir -p /projects/my_project
RUN chown node:node /projects/my_project

# If you are going to change WORKDIR value, 
# please also consider to change .env file
WORKDIR /projects/my_project

USER node
RUN npm install pm2 -g
CMD npm install && node /projects/my_project/src/index.js
```

How do I install a new module inside my container? `npm install` on host won't work because of `node_module` belongs to the `root` user. Is there any way to run it from the container?

Edit: Is there something "one-liner" that I could run outside the container to install a module?

Comment: Dis you try:
`docker exec container_id npm install module_name --save`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't mean to edit the `Dockerfile`, you can always execute a command on a running container with the `-it` flag:

```
$ docker run -it <container name> /usr/bin/npm install my_moduel
```

Answer (score 3):

First access inside container:

```
$ docker exec -it <container name> /bin/bash
```

Then inside container:

```
$ npm install pm2 -g
```

Comment: I don't want to install a global module, simply a new module. But, do I need to get into the container in order to do it? Is there something that I could to do from outside?

Comment: If you dont install global, simply `npm install pm2`. Or in case you don't mount your current source folder to default image workdir. Cd to source code directory then run install localy...

Answer (score 0):

You either

- a) want to install pm2 globally, which you need to run as root, so place your install before `USER node` so that you instead run at the default user (root), or
- b) you just want to install pm2 to use in your project, in which case just drop the `-g` flag which tells npm to install globally, and it will instead be in your project `node_modules`, and you can run it with `npx pm2` or `node_modules/.bin/pm2`, or programmatically from your `index.js` (for the latter I'd suggest adding it to your `package.json` and no manually installing it at all).

Comment: It isn't really nice to add it manually. Is there something "one-liner" that I could run outside the container to install a module?

Comment: "add it manually"? I'm not sure I understand, once it's in your package.json it'll just be installed by your `npm install`.